# crop bitmap in screen size from custom width

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

I have an big `ImageView` that loads an Image from Url and I puts it in a `ScrollView`.

I get bitmap from image view by this code :

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg =((BitmapDrawable) singleWallpaper.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Now I want to crop from position of `ScrollView` (ScrollX) to size of the screen and put them to new bitmap (What shows in just in display not others)

Answer (score 0):

1. First get the screen size by

   DisplayMetrics display=Context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
2. Now Crop the Bitmap

`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, display.widthPixels, display.heightPixels, true);`

Comment: when I try to set this bitmap as wallpaper ,the defult wallpaper of phone will set!!!

Answer (score 0):

Find the Phone Screen Height and Width by

```
DisplayMetrics display=Context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width=display.widthPixels;
int height=display.heightPixels;
```

Then Scale your Bitmap using

```
Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, display.widthPixels,display.heightPixels, true);
```

Now use this Bitmap

```
try {               
    getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bitmap);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper Set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After doing this all thing do not forget to give permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```